# Why does my UIPageViewController crop itself during curl transition?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller, uipageviewcontroller

In StoryBoard, I have setup two view controllers:

- PageViewRootViewController - this is just blank (in storyboard) as everything is setup programmatically.
- VillagerTextViewController - Storyboard sets the layout

Additionally, I have a ModelController (NSObject) that acts as the data source.

Everything is working fine. I can transition between pages, no warnings or errors and no crashes.

However, when transitioning, the bottom of the page is cropped off. I've been trying to fix it to no avail.

I can't post images yet so http://s10.postimg.org/qbjlat649/Screenshot_2013_04_20_22_12_04.png

The UIPageViewController is created in the viewDidLoad method of PageViewRootViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (!pageViewController) {
        NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin] forKey:UIPageViewControllerOptionSpineLocationKey];

        self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:options];
        self.pageViewController.delegate = self;

        VillagerTextViewController *startingViewController = [self.modelController viewControllerAtIndex:0 storyboard:self.storyboard];
        NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
        [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:NULL];

        self.pageViewController.dataSource = self.modelController;
        [self.pageViewController.view setClipsToBounds:NO];
        [self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
        [self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];

        [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

        self.view.gestureRecognizers = self.pageViewController.gestureRecognizers;
    }
}
```

In storyboard, I have the view for PageViewRootViewController set to popover width 768 and height 200. I also display this as a popover.

The VillagerTextViewController and ModelController do not have anything (in code or storyboard) explicitly related to size, frame, or bounds.

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:

Fixed with:

```
[self.pageViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x, self.view.bounds.origin.y, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height+600)];
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see you doing anything in your code about giving the UIPageViewController's `view` a frame. It's important not to omit that! I don't guarantee that this is the source of your problem, but it might be.

```
self.pageViewController.view.frame = ???????
```

The reason this doesn't *appear* to be a problem is that you're covering it up, as it were, by setting `clipsToBounds` to NO; thus you are making yourself unaware of where the frame is. Much better, I think, *not* to set `clipsToBounds` to NO, but to get the frame right.

Comment: Before posting this question, I tried multiple ways of setting the frame. I just resolved this by revisiting that after reading your reply. I ended up using:

    [self.pageViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x, self.view.bounds.origin.y, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height+600)];

Comment: That is what I said to do; `[self.pageViewController.view setFrame:` is exactly the same as `self.pageViewController.view.frame=`, the code that I told you to use. So my answer is right, yes?